# Push notification with php server?

Tags: c#, php, windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0

I somebody know a simple way to create a Push notification with php server...
I can't find any tutorial...

Thank

Comment: php? Why have you tagged it C#? Can you describe your problem better? See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Do you have access to google.com?

Answer (score 0):

Since push notifications simply involve posting XML to an HTTP server, it should be fairly simple to use PHP. I'm not overly familiar with PHP, but it looks like [`http_post_data`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-post-data.php) should handle the request.

These (.NET centric) pages should be of use:

- [Push Notifications Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)
- [How to: Send a Push Notification for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402545%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)